# Opening frame that is under the JavaFX program category

Tags: eclipse, video, javafx, jframe, mp4

Most of program is using JFrames throughout the application for all the different windows that can appear. However, I have to play an instructional video for the user inside a JFrame. I couldn't find a way to do this, so I had to make a JavaFX program. Is there a way to get directly from one of my JFrames to the JavaFX window?

I've been using syntax like this to open up other JFrame:

```
                dispose();
                paths pths = new paths();
                pths.setVisible(true);
```

However, when trying to open up the JavaFX using the above code, I get errors. I also can't create a new JavaFX inside an already existing project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure to understand your problem but in order to create a new frame in JavaFX. You have to create a new class with a new stage. Let's say you create a new class "newFrame" with the code below.

```
public void show(Stage stage){
   //define your root
   double width = 200;
   double height = 200;
   Scene scene = new Scene(root, width , height);
   stage.show();
}
```

You can show the new frame by using :

```
newFrame NT = new newFrame();
NT.show();
```